# regular-expression for mediawiki replace ==

Tags: regex, mediawiki

I am using mediawiki and I have the text
     `<div class="list-block"> == 2014 and beyond == <div id="list">My best day </div></div>`
I'm using the regular expresion:

```
%<div class="list-block"[^>]*>\n?<h2>(.+)</h2>\n?(<div id="list">)?(.*)(</div>)?\n?</div>\n</div>%sU
```

and it isn't working. 
It originally had 
`<div class="list-block">''' 2014 and beyond'''<div id="list">My best day </div></div>`
and the 
`%<div class="list-block"[^>]*>\n?<b>(.+)</b>\n?(<div id="list">)?(.*)(</div>)?\n?</div>\n</div>%sU` 
which worked great. I switched the `<b>` with the `<h2>` and now it isn't working. 
Any idea what I am doing wrong? (I don't mind removing the `<h2>` tags altogether but that doesn't work either).

Comment: Are you parsing the wikitext to HTML before applying the regular expression?

Comment: “Any idea what I am doing wrong?” [You're trying to parse HTML using regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/41071)

Comment: I know you shouldn't have HTML in a regular expression but why did it work with <b> and not with <h2>? How do I format it so I leave out the HTML? What is the correct way to write this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    '%<div class="list-block"[^>]*>\n?<h2>(.+)</h2>\n?(<div id="list">)?(.*)(</div>)?\n?</div>\n</div>%sU'`
```

Is working now, I'm not sure what the issue was, it could have been a mediawiki formatting issue.